# How do I iterate through the lines of a file in Scala using a custom newline delimeter?

Tags: scala, file-io, iterator, newline

I'd like to iterate over all the lines of a file in Scala but using the newline separator `\n%\n` instead of just `\n`. I'd like to be able to do this using the `scala.io.Source` abstract class.

Here's what I have so far:

```
object Main extends App {

  val lines = Source.fromFile("quotes.txt").getLines

  for {
    line <- lines
  } println(line)
}
```

This works fine using `\n` as a newline separator.

It seems that to be able to change the separator, I have to subclass `scala.io.Source.LineIterator` and implement my own  [`isNewLine` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source$LineIterator.html#isNewline(ch:Char):Boolean).

However, when I try to subclass `LineIterator` like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Source.LineIterator

class MyLineIterator extends LineIterator {
  override def isNewLine(c: Char) = c == "\n%\n"
}
```

I get the following error when trying to build with sbt:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /.../target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /.../Main.scala:6: value LineIterator is not a member of object scala.io.Source
[error] import scala.io.Source.LineIterator
[error]        ^
[error] /.../Main.scala:8: not found: type LineIterator
[error] class MyLineiterator extends LineIterator {
[error]                                 ^
[error] two errors found
```

Could somebody tell me why I can't import `LineIterator` and also provide a code snippet that allows me to specify a custom delimiter when iterating over the lines of a file?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `LineIterator` is a private inner class of `Source`. you might have to copy `LineIterator` and modify

Comment: In your example, `c == "\n%\n"` is never going to work because `c` is a `Char`, and a `Char` cannot be equal to a `String`, no matter the content.